# How to reduce Magento search autocomplete dropdown time delay?

Tags: search, ce-1.9.1.0

I am using Magento CE 1.9.1.0

How do I make dropdown suggestions for search input appear quicker when typing?

Comment: Faster database response.

Answer (score 0):

george,auto search process totally depends on server response time and search key return time,On Search focus.
initAutocomplete  function is called which call an ajax request .So in simple word, i can say it depends on result return time.

Comment: I notice that whatever I type it always takes about 2 seconds after last key press for the dropdown to update. Looking at the XHR timeline: there is about 900-1000ms TTFB and about 500-900ms for Content download. That is on a nearly empty store (15 products only). What kind of "Content download" are we talking about? This is a shared hosting but quite a fast one. How come a few words need 1s to download when I have full 100mbps connection to the host and all static files (images etc) literally fly. Is there a way to optimize this search?